# How to disable previous button on today's date?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I just want to disable the previous button on today's date.
The previous Button should be disabled when it comes to today's date.
Please help me to disable previous dates in the calender so that the user can only select the start date from today's date and onwards.
I am using moment.js for my Datepicker. Thank you! 
[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LUTy.jpg)

```js
var currDate = "";

function DateHelper(date) {
  if (date === undefined) {
    date = new Date();
  }

  // Require MomentJS: https://momentjs.com
  return {
    today: function today() {
      return moment(date).format('ll');
   
    },
    nextDay: function nextDay() {
      return moment(date).add(1, 'day').format('ll');
    },
    prevDay: function prevDay() {
      return moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('ll');
   
       
    },
    toString: function toString() {
      return moment(date).format('ll');
  
    } };

}


// Save/Load LocalStorage
function save(data) {
  localStorage["DiaryData"] = JSON.stringify(data);
}
function loadOrDefault(defaultObject) {
  if (localStorage["DiaryData"] !== undefined) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage["DiaryData"]);
  } else {
    return defaultObject;
  }
}

// Load data or setup default data
var allData = loadOrDefault({
  "2017-05-11": "Hello World.",
  "2017-05-31": "Hello World Again.",
  "2017-06-01": "Tomorrow is another day~" });


// todo: render day 
function setDiaryPage(pDate)
{
  currDate = pDate;
  $(".date").text(currDate);
  $("#diaryContent").val(getDiaryContent(currDate));
}



function getDiaryContent(pDate)
{
  return allData[DateHelper(pDate).toString()];
}
// todo: init
setDiaryPage(DateHelper().today());

// handling date choosing UI
$("#today").click(function () {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper().today());
  
});
$("#prevdate").click(function () {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper(currDate).prevDay());
 });
$("#nextdate").click(function () {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper(currDate).nextDay());
});

$('#diaryContent').bind('input propertychange', function () {
  onTextChange();
});

// handling content changes
function onTextChange() {
  allData[DateHelper(currDate).toString()] = $("#diaryContent").val();
  save(allData);
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.page {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.date {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev-button{text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: red !important;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;}

.row.no-gutters {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
}
.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing Date</title>
  
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  <button class="prev-button" style="" id="prevdate" href="#prev-date" onclick="myFunction()">previous date</a></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  <div class="date"></div></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  <button class="prev-button"  id="nextdate" href="#next-date">Next date</button></div>
<!-- <div class="col-lg-3">  <button class="prev-button"  id="today" href="#today">Today</button></div> -->
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what actual problem are you facing? What have you tried? Your snippet doesn't work so we can't easily see your existing functionality or the issue.

Comment: I just want to use this date picker for booking purpose, Now my code allows me to select previous dates. I just want to disable or hide prev button when date picker contains today's date  so that the user can only select the start date from today's date and onwards

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5268z1fL/11

Comment: @Ashwein that's a _requirement_, not a _problem_. This site is supposed to be about solving problems with your attempt at coding your requirement. As it happens it's not too difficult so I see that someone has helped you anyway, but normally if you were to ask about a more complex requirement, you'd be unlikely to get an answer unless you'd made some attempt at meeting the requirement yourself - we're here to help you, not to research the solution and then code it on your behalf.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Try This

```js
var currDate = "";

function DateHelper(date) {
  if (date === undefined) {
    date = new Date();
  }

  // Require MomentJS: https://momentjs.com
  return {
    today: function today() {
      return moment(date).format('ll');

    },
    nextDay: function nextDay() {
      return moment(date).add(1, 'day').format('ll');
    },
    prevDay: function prevDay() {
      return moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('ll');


    },
    toString: function toString() {
      return moment(date).format('ll');

    }
  };

}


// Save/Load LocalStorage
function save(data) {
  localStorage["DiaryData"] = JSON.stringify(data);
}

function loadOrDefault(defaultObject) {
  if (localStorage["DiaryData"] !== undefined) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage["DiaryData"]);
  } else {
    return defaultObject;
  }
}

// Load data or setup default data
var allData = loadOrDefault({
  "2017-05-11": "Hello World.",
  "2017-05-31": "Hello World Again.",
  "2017-06-01": "Tomorrow is another day~"
});


// todo: render day 
function setDiaryPage(pDate) {
  currDate = pDate;
  $(".date").text(currDate);
  $("#diaryContent").val(getDiaryContent(currDate));
}



function getDiaryContent(pDate) {
  return allData[DateHelper(pDate).toString()];
}
// todo: init
setDiaryPage(DateHelper().today());

// handling date choosing UI
$("#today").click(function() {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper().today());

});
$("#prevdate").click(function() {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper(currDate).prevDay());
  if (DateHelper().today() == $('.date').text()) {
    $("#prevdate").addClass('hide');
  } else {
    $("#prevdate").removeClass('hide');
  }
});
$("#nextdate").click(function() {
  setDiaryPage(DateHelper(currDate).nextDay());
  if (DateHelper().today() == $('.date').text()) {
    $("#prevdate").addClass('hide');
  } else {
    $("#prevdate").removeClass('hide');
  }
});

$('#diaryContent').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  onTextChange();
});

// handling content changes
function onTextChange() {
  allData[DateHelper(currDate).toString()] = $("#diaryContent").val();
  save(allData);
}
if (DateHelper().today() == $('.date').text()) {
  $("#prevdate").addClass('hide');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.date {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red !important;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutters>[class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters>[class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing Date</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <button class="prev-button" style="" id="prevdate" href="#prev-date" onclick="myFunction()">previous date</a></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  <div class="date"></div></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  <button class="prev-button"  id="nextdate" href="#next-date">Next date</button></div>
    <!-- <div class="col-lg-3">  <button class="prev-button"  id="today" href="#today">Today</button></div> -->
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```